R Markdown parameterized pdf output using xelatex engine failed to compile when include ggplot
I'm using R Markdown to bulk generate parameterized pdf reports. I have no problem running each code chunk and no problem knitting single pdf. But when I run the lapply() function at the bottom, three (the "cut" variable in diamonds dataset has five categories) pdfs are generated successfully but I'm stuck at the fourth one, "Very Good". I get error messages instead:

WHAT DID I TRY:
I have re-installed R, RStudio, tinytex, and every package used in my code.
I have pinpointed that the issue has something to do with the ggplot code chunk - hence, all five pdfs are generated successfully if I exclude that code chunk.
UPDATE:

As folks pointed out below, the breakage running lapply() function is caused by the blank space in "Very Good", and potentially, because of how Windows system cannot deal with blank space in path name. But these cannot explain why the code stuck at "Very Good" ONLY WHEN I INCLUDE A PLOT, in other words, when I take the plot code chunk out, the old lapply() code works for "Very Good" and other categories in my parameter "cut". Appreciate if somebody could get to the bottom of this issue.
A couple of us are getting a new error message regarding fontspec
saying that fontspec requires "xelatex or laulatex" but I've already defined "latex_engine: xelatex" in my YAML. I'd really appreciate if folks could pinpoint this issue as well or let me know if there's any other way to change the default font to user defined font such as "Times New Roman" in another way to by pass this fontspec issue?


CODE:
The following is everything I have in my current "testing_for_stackoverflow.Rmd" file that results in the fontspec error message:
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
tables: true
graphics: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \usepackage{graphicx}
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
  - \setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
  - \newcommand{\bcenter}{\begin{center}} 
  - \newcommand{\ecenter}{\end{center}}
params:
  cut: "Very Good"
---
\fontsize{10}{12}
\selectfont

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE,
                      message = FALSE,
                      fig.align = 'center',
                      include = TRUE,
                      tinytex.tlmgr_update = FALSE,
                      results='asis',
                      fig.dim = c(7, 2.5))
pacman::p_load(tidyverse)

```


## I'm using "diamonds" dataset and cut is my parameter

```{r}
filter(diamonds, cut == params$cut) %>%
  ggplot(aes(color, price)) +
  geom_boxplot()

```

```{r}
kableExtra::kable(head(filter(diamonds, cut == params$cut))) 
```

Run this code in the console to produce several output files:
library(tidyverse)
lapply(unique(diamonds$cut), function(i) {
  rmarkdown::render(input = "testing_for_stackoverflow.Rmd",
                    params = list(cut = i),
                    rmarkdown::pdf_document(),
                    output_dir = "out/",
                    output_file = paste0(i, ".pdf"))
})


Welcome to SO! Unfortunately we can't run code or render an Rmd from images. Instead simply copy & paste your Rmd code as text into your question. For more on how to ask a good question see How to make a great R reproducible example.

@stefan Thanks for the tips! I've edited my post but it's just the YAML part appears wacky when I paste it as text. Hope it still makes sense if I keep the screenshot..

You are calling rmarkdown::render from within a document?   That's strange.  But the code you posted says the parameter is speed, while your document has a parameter named cut.

@user2554330 Thanks for your attention! No, don't run the final lapply() code within this Rmd file. Cut and paste it in the console to run. And sorry about the typo - the parameter is cut, not speed (speed was another testing doc where I use the cars dataset).

I've edited your question to make this a bit clearer.  I don't get the error you got when I run it; I get a somewhat different one, complaining about fonts.  When I remove the fontspec package and the font specification I get no error.  But I'm on a Mac; your error looks like a problem with Windows paths.

@user2554330 Thanks for editing my question! And I am having the same fontspec issue now - this is definitely a new issue because I did NOT have it by the time I posted my question. And the fontspec error message doesn't make sense because I have defined latex_engine: xelatex in my YAML. Any idea to tackle this issue? xelatex is important because I have to use Time New Roman throughout my report.

I've spotted the issue now.  In your call to rmarkdown::render(), you are specifying output_format as rmarkdown::pdf_document().  This overrides the output: section in the YAML.  If you want to specify things as in your code example, use rmarkdown::pdf_document(latex_engine = "xelatex").

@user2554330 YES! You're right. The fontspec error is solved. THANKS so much!!

The fourth document rendered (or rather not rendered) is the one containing a blank in the supposed intermediary and final filenames: Very Good.... Guessing from the error message, the filename might be falsely interpreted as two separate instructions (undefined control sequence).
Does replacing the blank solve the issue? One approach:
lapply(make.names(unique(diamonds$cut)), ...)

instead of:
lapply(unique(diamonds$cut), ...)

HOWEVER, make.names() will return "Very.Good" in the first argument of lapply() but since params = "Very Good", not data will be found in the rendering process. As a result, the pdf output of "Very Good" returns NA for all the data points being used.
So, the ultimate solution is to create a new variable using make.names(cut) and use the new variable as a parameter in the Rmd file for this parameterized report code to run (in a Windows system).

Appreciate the solution - it definitely addresses the issue caused by my oversight of blank space issue in file names and yes, using make.names() indeed prevents the previous error message: "! Undefined control sequence." I can get all the five pdf output files now. HOWEVER, for the "Very Good" file, the plot and table both have defined parameters, axes for plot and column names for table but no content. Please don't put too much time to tackle this issue. I will use a token variable instead of cut for the parameter.

The more pressing issue now is (please see my conversation with @user2554330) I'm getting a new error message saying "fontspec requires xelatex or laulatex" but I've already defined "latex_engine: xelatex" in my YAML. I have to use "Times New Roman" font in my report so fontspec is important to me. Any idea on this issue? THANKS in advance!

Over at the TeX forum you might get lucky, see e. g. this answer. In the case of RStudio you might also try setting Tools > Options > Global Options > Sweave > Typeset ... using to "XeLaTeX".

This fontspec error is solved by @user2554330. See comments above. THANKS!
